# NNTP command to get count of available newsgroups

Tags: nntp, usenet

Is there an NNTP command to return the count of NewsGroups on an USENET server? (Without having to retrieving the entire list.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such a command is not available in [RFC 3977](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3977).

Comment: Thanks - it was worth a shot! :-)

Comment: you can see *new groups* however

Comment: Is there a "standard" way to only retrieving new posts in a group? (and I found `newnews` command disabled by many usenet server?)